# Having issues while converting c source file to use in C#

Tags: .net, dllexport

I am bit new with these kind of issues, I have a running C project and I want to use that in my C# library but I am not able to find any help.

Comment: You cannot really just convert them like that. I'm not a C guy, but the concepts of the languages are so different.

Comment: Stack Overflow is an excellent resource for fairly specific questions.  It isn't suitable for vague and open-ended questions, and the people here generally don't like the feeling that they're doing your work for you.  Come up with a plan and start working on it.  If you run into specific problems, feel free to ask here (and please provide enough information to make it possible to solve).

Comment: Define "i have a running C project and i want to use that in my C# library."  Do you want your C# library to call an executable written in C?  Do you want it to reference a library written in C?  Do you want to port the C code to C# code?

Comment: look there is project on which i am working now, and the basic code is written using C and i need to call that basic in C# and have to do the rest of the work in C# after that. So i know that i need to have some DLL or some CLR application but i dont know how to do it, that i what i am asking. I dont want anyone to work for me, i just need some guidence. i hope you guys can help and guide me.

Comment: I want to C# to call the C code first and then the coding of C# which i will be doing after that.

Comment: @Rahul - Use P/Invoke - After you at least attempt it come back with a specfic question and I will answer it.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is p/invoke (you used the dllexport tag), here is some introductory reading:

[Calling Win32 DLLs in C# with P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx)

[Platform Invoke Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx)

If you have a specific p/invoke question, post the signature of the native method and any types involved as well as your managed attempt.

Comment: How can i use p/invoke when i dont have the dll with me of that code?

Comment: No, i meant i have the source code but i dont have the dll of that.

Comment: That code is written in VC++ 6.0 workspace and in that i can not find the enable CLR option, what should i do?

Comment: I'm sorry @rahul, you have completely lost me. Maybe you can start at the beginning and describe the problem you're having in detail?

Comment: Sir, i have a project done in VC++ 6.0 which has a c source file, and i need t have that as basic for building a C# application, so i want to convert that to some managed extensions so that i can make it happen. Let me know if you want to ask anymore questions.

Comment: can i have your messenger id or something so that i can talk to you live on messenger?

Comment: The fastest path will be for you to compile the C code into a DLL. Then you can use p/Invoke as described in the articles I linked to call the methods in the DLL. If you cannot compile it to a DLL, you may have to translate it entirely into C#. This is not optimal because presumably the C code is already tested and working.

Comment: yes sir that code is entirely tested and working but how can i compile that to a dll?

Comment: I have not used VC6 is a very long time, but it *should* be a simple matter of changing the Configuration Type from `Application (.exe)` to `Dynamic Library (.dll)` and then adding a .DEF file (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx). Since you say this is C (not C++), you won't have to worry about name mangling issues (i.e. extern "C").

Comment: hello sir, i have done some work there on the file and successfull generated the filename.exe.intermediate.manifest file and the other files there, but these are without the \clr, if i try to build that with \clr support then it gives me error of not support avaiable for that \clr. What should be my next ste.?

Comment: You do not need /clr support in the native DLL to p/Invoke to it. That switch is basically there to provide a mixed-mode assembly (i.e. managed C++). You don't need a manifest either, just a plain-old-dll.

Comment: sir i am not able to generate the dll there that is the main issue which i am having. As far as now i have been able to generate is that manifest file there. Can we talk on messenger ?

Comment: I'm not available for consulting at this time. I come here when I have a little time and try to answer questions as I can. "I am not able to generate the dll" is not enough information to help you out. My recommendation to you would be to start a new question. State that you are trying to build a C file as a DLL. Post all relevant error messages. Post any code relevant to those error messages. Post a link to that question here so that I see it.

Comment: Hi again, i have successfully generated the dll and then i have put that in the p/invoker and got the marshal dll, but how can i use the functions of my dll in C# now?

Comment: Read the articles I linked in my answer. They describe the various ways of declaring an exported method and calling it from C#. If there is a specific function that you're having trouble p/invoking, post a new question. Post the declaration of the C function along with any user-defined type parameters.